# Using file groovy scripts in Elasticsearch Watcher Condition fails

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, elasticsearch-watcher

I want to have a watch that alerts when the count of documents of a given query is between a specific range of values.  I created a simple file script, value_between.groovy, to test this.  The script contains the following:

```
return ctx.payload.hits.total > lower_limit && ctx.payload.hits.total < upper_limit
```

My watch condition is the following:

```
  "condition":
    {
      "script":
      {
        "file": "value_between",
        "params":
        {
          "lower_limit": 50,
          "upper_limit": 100
        }
      }
    }
```

Each time this watch runs, it fails, with the following log message.

```
[2016-10-12 13:22:27,285][ERROR][watcher.condition.script ] [elk-node] failed to execute [script] condition for [test-watch_174-2016-10-12T12:29:20.042Z]
ScriptException[failed to run file script [value_between] using lang [groovy]]; nested: MissingPropertyException[No such property: value for class: 5614867be4d02007620aca2099ecab8f6f899536];
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: The version is 2.3.3

Comment: Works for me. Can you share the watch definition as well?